# Good design for angular2 dataflow?

Tags: angular, workflow, code-injection, dataflow

After working with angular2 for some time, I still cannot see one good way to share data across my application. I have come across several methods, however it's unclear as to what is the desirable approach to pass data from one component to another. Here are ways to pass/share data that I am aware of :

1. Use a service and inject in components that need it, apart from 
   regular CRUD, I see no problem with keeping variables inside this service such as 'selectedClient' or 'viewType'.
2. Emit events (from children to notify parent) with @Output, and listen 
   in the parent.
3. Get handle of children with ViewChild('childrenComponent') and call functions on it directly
4. Pass data to children directly using [someVarible]='someData' , @Input notation.
5. Pass data using , router.navigate and routerLink to components.
6. use ngOnChanges, onModelChange for change detection in the components/model

I would like to use simple 5 step form as an example.

Assuming we start at step 1, we call a service to retrieve a list of cars.
In our template we iterate through the cars (let car of cars) and we have click events on our links (click)='selectCar(car)' to set the selected car. Now, if I wanted this 'car' object to be passed to Step2 etc, I could pass it using (3,4,5); however, if I go back to Step1, I dont want to have to send the data back, so how do I keep state?

The simplest solution we have found is to keep some variables in the services, and simply use (click)='carService.setSelectedCar(car)' in the templates directly, however it simply feels wrong and I am unaware if there is any potential issues with using it this way.

I couldn't find any examples of a recurring pattern that we can use across the whole application. Sometimes we use method 1, sometimes 2,3 sometimes 4,5 and it's hard to find middle ground.

Is there anything wrong with using services in the templates? Are there design patterns/best practices for dataflow in angular2? Are there some general rules that are best followed to have greater separation of responsibilities between services/components?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for a clear dataflow-flow design is using the **redux architecture**.

> Instead of mutating the state directly, you specify the mutations you
>   want to happen with plain objects called actions. Then you write a
>   special function called a reducer to decide how every action
>   transforms the entire application's state.

Here you can find more information about the [motivation](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Motivation.html) to use redux.

There are some nice packages out there:

- [ngrx-store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) "RxJS powered state management for Angular2 apps, inspired by Redux". This [nice tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-introduction-to-redux-1cf18af27e6e#.w221ly5gu) show the usage of it.
- [ng2-redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng2-redux), a redux implementation for
  angular2.